# Material UI: Parsing error: Identifier 'Switch' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I need to use the Material UI [Switch component](https://material-ui.com/components/switches/) along with react-router-dom Switch in one of the components.
Here is how I have imported them into the react component:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Switch from "@material-ui/core/Switch";
```

But of course compiler error shows:

> Parsing error: Identifier 'Switch' has already been declared.

Is there any way to use one of the import as a fully qualified one to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to rename it as you are already using a `<Switch />` component from **react-router-dom**. Try as the following:

```
import MaterialSwitch from "@material-ui/core/Switch";
```

And also don't forget to update your references in that file from `<Switch />` to `<MaterialSwitch />` where it is applicable.